# Mvvmcross localization in UWP

Tags: c#, localization, resources, uwp, mvvmcross

What is a modern approach to use localization in UWP?

JsonLocalization plugin for UWP did not pull neither Json nor ResourseLoader plugins. Moreover, it did not install any bootstrap files (not sure if they still needed in UWP).

Based on assumption that it works correctly without bootstraping and that plugin already contains all necessary stuff, i implemented sample like it was instructed in video and got "||ViewHeader" string instead of localized one. And json content is obviously something like

```
{
    "ViewHeader":"Test view header"
}
```

I added breakpoint to NativeLanguageConverter.Convert and figured out that value.TextProvider.ResourceLoader is null. I have added all those plugins manually, but error is the same - seems they are unregsitered, so i have to bootstrap them.

What should i do in this case?

UPDATE: Indeed, the problem is about missing bootstraps: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Plugins/issues/113

However, even after adding them, i'm still getting string in format "|%AssemblyName%|%ViewmodelName%|%KeyName%" instead of "%ValueName%". In debugger, i can see that dictionary contains proper key-value pair, but it somehow returns not value, but a formatted key.

Comment: Bootstrap files are needed. But you need to create them manually. At least that happened to me in version 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending several hours, i had figured out the working combination.

In order to fix the issue, i have to create a different LanguageBinders for different ViewModels.

```
public IMvxLanguageBinder FirstViewModelTextSource
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxLanguageBinder(GeneralConstants.LocalizationGeneralNamespace, "FirstViewModel");
        }
    }
```

And then on the view:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstViewModelTextSource,Converter={StaticResource Language},ConverterParameter=ViewHeader,FallbackValue=ViewHeader,Mode=OneTime}" 
                   Margin="10,0,10,50" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```